# Rarest bronze badges are missing from this user's profile

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

I was visiting [Robert Cartaino's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) when I saw that there was nothing in the Bronze badges section in his profile as seen here:
[image]

I don't get it. It seems to be a bug since I have badges shown in the Bronze badge section on [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278543/pythonmaster) as seen here:
[image]

Why doesn't his profile have anything for rarest Bronze badges while I do? If it is an update or feature that seemingly I don't know, please tell me. Oh, ***I am not stalking people!***

Comment: he sold the bronze to make a statue of Jon Skeet

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Comment: I wouldn't know, not my downvote

Comment: "What's wrong with my question?" Someone possibly thinks it's *not* a bug, doesn't like the way you presented the question, is a member of the AFCM (anti free-circle movement), had many tabs open and dvoted the wrong question in the confusion, or, got out of the wrong side of bed.  Such is Meta. It's annoying, but meh what can you do if they don't comment... +1 to counter the dvote (plus extra)